# Generate CSR in Android (java or kotlin) Using BouncyCastle(or SpongyCastle) With ED25519

Tags: csr, ed25519

is there any way to generate CSR with pem format in android using "ed25519 keypair" ?
we can use BouncyCastle (SpongyCastle) to generate and sign csr , but with "RSA" algorithm and keypair.
i want to use "ed25519" algorithm & keypair.